# R Divide all values of a column by the values in same column but different group

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table as follows -

```
library(data.table)
dt <- structure(list(date = structure(c(17956L, 17959L, 17960L, 
                                  17962L, 17963L, 17966L, 17967L, 17968L, 17969L, 17970L, 17973L, 
                                  17974L, 17975L, 17976L, 17977L, 17980L, 17981L, 17982L, 17983L, 
                                  17984L, 17956L, 17959L, 17960L, 17961L, 17962L, 17963L, 17966L, 
                                  17967L, 17968L, 17980L, 17981L, 17982L, 17983L, 17984L), class = c("IDate", "Date")), 
               group = c("A", "A", "A", "A", 
                          "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
                          "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
                          "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
                          "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"), 
               value = c(43.7425, 
                         43.9625, 43.8825, 43.125, 43.2275, 44.725, 45.2275, 45.4275, 
                         45.9325, 46.53, 47.005, 46.6325, 47.04, 48.7725, 47.7625, 47.185, 
                         46.6975, 47.1175, 47.18, 47.4875, 12.31, 12.51, 12.7, 12.4, 12.63, 
                         12.93, 13.18, 13.23, 13.35, 14.27, 14.5, 14.25, 13.88, 13.71)), 
          row.names = c(NA, -34L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
> dt
          date group   value
 1: 2019-03-01     A 43.7425
 2: 2019-03-04     A 43.9625
 3: 2019-03-05     A 43.8825
 5: 2019-03-07     A 43.1250
 6: 2019-03-08     A 43.2275
 7: 2019-03-11     A 44.7250
 8: 2019-03-12     A 45.2275
 9: 2019-03-13     A 45.4275
10: 2019-03-14     A 45.9325
11: 2019-03-15     A 46.5300
12: 2019-03-18     A 47.0050
13: 2019-03-19     A 46.6325
14: 2019-03-20     A 47.0400
15: 2019-03-21     A 48.7725
16: 2019-03-22     A 47.7625
17: 2019-03-25     A 47.1850
18: 2019-03-26     A 46.6975
19: 2019-03-27     A 47.1175
20: 2019-03-28     A 47.1800
21: 2019-03-29     A 47.4875
22: 2019-03-01     B 12.3100
23: 2019-03-04     B 12.5100
24: 2019-03-05     B 12.7000
25: 2019-03-06     B 12.4000
26: 2019-03-07     B 12.6300
27: 2019-03-08     B 12.9300
28: 2019-03-11     B 13.1800
29: 2019-03-12     B 13.2300
30: 2019-03-13     B 13.3500
31: 2019-03-25     B 14.2700
32: 2019-03-26     B 14.5000
33: 2019-03-27     B 14.2500
34: 2019-03-28     B 13.8800
35: 2019-03-29     B 13.7100
```

I want to divide all the elements in column `value` by the elements of the same column in `group A` and create a new column called `ratio`.
The sample output will look something like the following.

```
          date group   value  ratio
22: 2019-03-01     B 12.3100  12.3100/43.7425 = 0.28141
23: 2019-03-04     B 12.5100  12.5100/43.9625 = 0.28456
24: 2019-03-05     B 12.7000  12.7000/43.8825 = 0.28940
```

Please note -

1. In the `ratio` column, I have shown the calculation to make it easy to understand. I need only the ratio values in the `ratio` column.
2. Groups are indexed by the date column.
3. There are missing values in both of these columns. A little bit of error handling will help.

I hope there is a simple way to solve this problem using `data.table` library.

Comment: I am still not sure what your desired output. What's the dimension?

Comment: The radio seems like the value of group B divide group A with the same date.

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 2):

I can provide a tidyverse approach.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df %>%   
  pivot_wider(names_from = group, values_from = value) %>% 
  mutate(ratio = B/A)
```

Comment: That's a somewhat different shape of the result. The `data.table` equivalent would be `dcast(dt, date~group)[, ratio:=B/A]`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one line solution using data.table. It does take care of missing values.

```
setDT(dt)[, ratio := value/value[group=="A"] , date]
          date group   value     ratio
 1: 2019-03-01     A 43.7425 1.0000000
 2: 2019-03-04     A 43.9625 1.0000000
 3: 2019-03-05     A 43.8825 1.0000000
 4: 2019-03-07     A 43.1250 1.0000000
 5: 2019-03-08     A 43.2275 1.0000000
 6: 2019-03-11     A 44.7250 1.0000000
 7: 2019-03-12     A 45.2275 1.0000000
 8: 2019-03-13     A 45.4275 1.0000000
 9: 2019-03-14     A 45.9325 1.0000000
10: 2019-03-15     A 46.5300 1.0000000
11: 2019-03-18     A 47.0050 1.0000000
12: 2019-03-19     A 46.6325 1.0000000
13: 2019-03-20     A 47.0400 1.0000000
14: 2019-03-21     A 48.7725 1.0000000
15: 2019-03-22     A 47.7625 1.0000000
16: 2019-03-25     A 47.1850 1.0000000
17: 2019-03-26     A 46.6975 1.0000000
18: 2019-03-27     A 47.1175 1.0000000
19: 2019-03-28     A 47.1800 1.0000000
20: 2019-03-29     A 47.4875 1.0000000
21: 2019-03-01     B 12.3100 0.2814197
22: 2019-03-04     B 12.5100 0.2845607
23: 2019-03-05     B 12.7000 0.2894092
24: 2019-03-06     B 12.4000        NA
25: 2019-03-07     B 12.6300 0.2928696
26: 2019-03-08     B 12.9300 0.2991151
27: 2019-03-11     B 13.1800 0.2946898
28: 2019-03-12     B 13.2300 0.2925211
29: 2019-03-13     B 13.3500 0.2938749
30: 2019-03-25     B 14.2700 0.3024266
31: 2019-03-26     B 14.5000 0.3105091
32: 2019-03-27     B 14.2500 0.3024354
33: 2019-03-28     B 13.8800 0.2941925
34: 2019-03-29     B 13.7100 0.2887076
          date group   value     ratio
```

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is to perform an *update join* of `dt` with the subset `dt[group == "A"]` on `date`. This will take care of missing values automatically:

```
dt[dt[group == "A"], on = "date", ratio := x.value / i.value][]
```

> ```
>           date group   value     ratio
>  1: 2019-03-01     A 43.7425 1.0000000
>  2: 2019-03-04     A 43.9625 1.0000000
>  3: 2019-03-05     A 43.8825 1.0000000
>  4: 2019-03-07     A 43.1250 1.0000000
>  5: 2019-03-08     A 43.2275 1.0000000
>  6: 2019-03-11     A 44.7250 1.0000000
>  7: 2019-03-12     A 45.2275 1.0000000
>  8: 2019-03-13     A 45.4275 1.0000000
>  9: 2019-03-14     A 45.9325 1.0000000
> 10: 2019-03-15     A 46.5300 1.0000000
> 11: 2019-03-18     A 47.0050 1.0000000
> 12: 2019-03-19     A 46.6325 1.0000000
> 13: 2019-03-20     A 47.0400 1.0000000
> 14: 2019-03-21     A 48.7725 1.0000000
> 15: 2019-03-22     A 47.7625 1.0000000
> 16: 2019-03-25     A 47.1850 1.0000000
> 17: 2019-03-26     A 46.6975 1.0000000
> 18: 2019-03-27     A 47.1175 1.0000000
> 19: 2019-03-28     A 47.1800 1.0000000
> 20: 2019-03-29     A 47.4875 1.0000000
> 21: 2019-03-01     B 12.3100 0.2814197
> 22: 2019-03-04     B 12.5100 0.2845607
> 23: 2019-03-05     B 12.7000 0.2894092
> 24: 2019-03-06     B 12.4000        NA
> 25: 2019-03-07     B 12.6300 0.2928696
> 26: 2019-03-08     B 12.9300 0.2991151
> 27: 2019-03-11     B 13.1800 0.2946898
> 28: 2019-03-12     B 13.2300 0.2925211
> 29: 2019-03-13     B 13.3500 0.2938749
> 30: 2019-03-25     B 14.2700 0.3024266
> 31: 2019-03-26     B 14.5000 0.3105091
> 32: 2019-03-27     B 14.2500 0.3024354
> 33: 2019-03-28     B 13.8800 0.2941925
> 34: 2019-03-29     B 13.7100 0.2887076
>           date group   value     ratio
> ```

Note that this approach returns `NA` in row 24 because there is no corresponding date `2019-03-06` in group `A`.

#### Benchmark

As several solutions have been proposed, I was wondering what the differences are in terms of execution speed and memory consumption:

1. "group": [Saurabh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66644014/3817004) which groups by `date`
2. "join": update join as suggested in this answer
3. "reshape", "reshape2": the `data.table` version of [TarJae's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66644000/3817004) but heavily extended to return the same result as the other answers, in two flavours

For benchmarking, the `bench` package is used with varying problem sizes. The effect of missing values which causes some no matches on date is simulated as well.

This is achieved by creating separate data.tables for each group `A` and `B`, resp., with 10% more rows than the specified problem size `n`. From these two data.tables `n` rows each are sampled and combined into the actual benchmark data.table `dt0`. `dt0` has 2 x `n` rows.

Also note that each benchmark run starts with a fresh copy of `dt0` because some approaches modify the input data *in place*.

```
library(bench)
library(ggplot2)
bm <- press(
  n = 10^(3:7)
  , {
    nx <- as.integer(n * 1.1)
    dates <- seq(as.IDate("1970-01-01"), by = 1L, length.out = nx)
    dtA <- data.table(date = dates,  group = "A", value = (1:nx) * pi)
    dtB <- data.table(date = dates,  group = "B", value = (1:nx) * 2*pi)
    set.seed(123)
    dt0 <- rbind(dtA[sample(nx, n)], dtB[sample(nx, n)])
    setorder(dt0, group, date)
    mark(
      join = {
        dt <- copy(dt0)
        dt[dt[group == "A"], on = "date", ratio := x.value / i.value]
      }, 
      group = {
        dt <- copy(dt0)
        dt[, ratio := value/value[group=="A"] , date]  
      },
      reshape = {
        dt <- copy(dt0)
        dcast(dt, date ~ group)[, c("ratioA", "ratioB") := .(A/A, B/A)][
          , melt(.SD, measure.vars = list(value = c("A", "B"), ratio = c("ratioA", "ratioB")), 
                 variable.name = "group")][
                   !(is.na(value) & is.na(ratio))][
                     , group := c("A", "B")[group]]
      },
      reshape2 = {
        dt <- copy(dt0)
        dcast(dt, date ~ group)[, c("ratioA", "ratioB") := .(rep(1.0, .N), B/A)][
          , melt(.SD, measure.vars = patterns(value = "^[AB]", ratio = "^ratio"), 
                 variable.name = "group")][
                   , group := c("A", "B")[group]][
                     !is.na(value)]
      },
      check = function(x,y) all.equal(x, y, check.attributes = FALSE),
      min_iterations = 3L
    )
  }
)
```

The benchmark results are shown in the table below

```
 bm[, 1:10]
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 20 x 10
>    expression        n      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
>    <bch:expr>    <dbl> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
>  1 join           1000   3.19ms   3.88ms  243.      355.42KB    2.10    116     1   477.13ms
>  2 group          1000   2.27ms   2.81ms  342.      137.24KB    2.05    167     1    488.5ms
>  3 reshape        1000   4.74ms   6.26ms  155.      805.56KB    2.12     73     1   472.21ms
>  4 reshape2       1000   4.68ms   6.18ms  159.      797.66KB    2.09     76     1    479.4ms
>  5 join          10000   4.86ms   5.96ms  161.         1.9MB    0        81     0   503.38ms
>  6 group         10000  18.68ms  19.77ms   49.7     930.32KB    4.52     22     2   442.34ms
>  7 reshape       10000   9.13ms  11.59ms   83.9       4.29MB    0        42     0   500.68ms
>  8 reshape2      10000  10.58ms  12.83ms   76.7       4.21MB    0        39     0   508.78ms
>  9 join         100000  23.43ms  28.14ms   35.2      17.41MB    0        18     0   512.06ms
> 10 group        100000 187.33ms 192.88ms    5.18      9.13MB    2.59      2     1   385.76ms
> 11 reshape      100000   51.8ms  57.67ms   17.4      39.31MB    2.17      8     1   460.72ms
> 12 reshape2     100000  50.59ms  56.78ms   17.3      38.55MB    0         9     0   520.46ms
> 13 join        1000000 183.66ms 184.12ms    5.40    172.53MB    0         3     0    555.4ms
> 14 group       1000000    1.83s    1.98s    0.486    86.12MB    2.43      3    15      6.18s
> 15 reshape     1000000 473.52ms 492.22ms    2.05    389.47MB    0         3     0      1.46s
> 16 reshape2    1000000 498.48ms 505.92ms    1.97    381.84MB    0         3     0      1.52s
> 17 join       10000000    2.01s    2.44s    0.432     1.68GB    0.576     3     4      6.95s
> 18 group      10000000   18.41s    18.7s    0.0531   860.1MB    2.76      3   156     56.46s
> 19 reshape    10000000    6.07s    6.46s    0.142      3.8GB    0.237     3     5      21.1s
> 20 reshape2   10000000    6.01s    6.02s    0.161     3.73GB    0.322     3     6     18.65s
> ```

or can be visualised by

```
autoplot(bm)
```

[image]

Note the logarithmic timescale.

The *group* approach is fastest for smaller problem sizes. With increasing problem size this method is overtaken by the other approaches, in particular the *join* approach. For n = 10<sup>7</sup>, *join* is about seven times faster than *group*. Astonishingly, the *reshape* approaches are second fastest despite the data is reshaped forth and back.

While *group* is becoming comparatively slow with larger problem sizes it has the smallest memory footprint (`mem_alloc`).

Note that all timings are below 20 seconds even for the largest problem size. So, any speed differences may only matter if the operation is repeated many times.

Answer (score 1):

We can also do

```
library(data.table)
dt[order(date, group), ratio := value/first(value), date]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the answer does not show the output which hides the fact that the answer returns a `ratio` of 1.0 in row 24 although there is no corresponding `date` of  2019-03-06 in group `A`. This is in contrast to the other answers which return `NA` here, including [OP's own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66644014/3817004).